# How to run commands in Docker container

Tags: docker, clang, jpeg

Hello I m trying to follow the step by step guid to build jpeg xl (I m on windows and try to build a x64 version for linux)

after:

```
docker run -u root:root -it --rm -v C:\Users\fred\source\tools\jpegxl\jpeg-xl-master -w /jpeg-xl gcr.io/jpegxl/jpegxl-builder
```

I have the container running but I don't know how to run the command inside :

```
CC=clang-6.0 CXX=clang++-6.0 ./ci.sh opt
```

I tried CC=clang-6.0 CXX=clang++-6.0 ./ci.sh opt and I get **./ci.sh: No such file or directory** no command seems to work when I do "ls" it display nothing

Does someone knows how to get this to build?

Comment: if I do the docker run command above, I get a bash prompt. If I do the docker exec -it container_id bash, I also get the bash prompt and if I do docker run -it <image> /bin/bash it also gives me the bash prompt. if I click on the CLI button in docker and type /bin/bash I also get the command prompt.

but in all of them if I do CC=clang-6.0 CXX=clang++-6.0 ./ci.sh opt I get ./ci.sh: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you start a bash terminal inside the container:

```sh
docker run -it <image> /bin/bash
```

I believe `/bin/bash` is missing from your `docker run` command. As a result, you are executing the command for clang inside your own environment, not the container.

Comment: hello it doesn't work either, in fact after my command I get the same bash terminal as if I do the one you gave me. Also in docker if click the CLI button and type /bin/bash I also the bash prompt but I stile cannot run the CC command and even ls doesn't display any thing

Comment: Thanks for verifying. It seems like you are using an existing image that should have clang installed. What if you execute the following in the container `cd ~` followed by
`find . -name ci.sh`? The latter would try to find the file you want to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variables by using `-e`

Example

```
-e CC=clang-6.0 -e CXX=clang++-6.0
```

The full command to log in into your container:

```
docker run -u root:root -it --rm -e CC=clang-6.0 -e CXX=clang++-6.0 -v C:\Users\fred\source\tools\jpegxl\jpeg-xl-master -w /jpeg-xl gcr.io/jpegxl/jpegxl-builder /bin/bash
```

Comment: Hello Matias I tried with the -e command and it seems that clang is stile unknown

"Unknown clang version" any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Maybe, there is somethin wrong in the documentation https://gitlab.com/wg1/jpeg-xl/-/blob/master/doc/developing_in_docker.md

Answer (score 0):

They have updated the image without updating the command so the command is

```
CC=clang-7 CXX=clang++-7 ./ci.sh opt
```

The discution is here:
[Can't build from docker image "Unknown clang version"](https://gitlab.com/wg1/jpeg-xl/-/issues/15)